# Objective-C: App runs only once, though compiles perfectly

Tags: objective-c, crash, alert, viewcontroller

I have created an app that compiles ok but, when I try to play again, the simulator crashes and I can't figure out why. The relevant parts in my code are as follows:

```
iFocus2AppDelegate.m


- (void) flipToGameScreen:(NSInteger *)aMode aLevel:(NSInteger*)aLevel 
{
    NSInteger *myMode = aMode;
    NSInteger *myLevel = aLevel;

    GameScreenViewController *aGameScreenView = [[GameScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameScreen" mode:myMode level:myLevel bundle:nil];
    [self setGameScreenViewController:aGameScreenView];
    [aGameScreenView release];
    gameScreenViewController.view.frame =[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

    //animation
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:window cache: YES];
    [viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.window addSubview:[gameScreenViewController view]];
    [UIView commitAnimations];      

 }


GameScreenViewController.m


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil mode:(NSInteger *)myMode level:(NSInteger *)myLevel bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil 
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) 
    {
        // Custom initialization.
        self.selectedMode = myMode;
        self.selectedLevel = myLevel;

    }
    return self;
}

- (void) finished
{   
    [myTimer invalidate];
    myTimer = nil;
    [myTimer release];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"GameOver"
                 message:@"Do Something"
                 delegate:self
                 cancelButtonTitle:nil
                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Play Again"];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Show HiScores"];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle: @"Setup New Game"];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        //PlayAgain
        iFocus2AppDelegate *mainDelegate = (iFocus2AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [mainDelegate flipToGameScreen:selectedMode aLevel:selectedLevel];
        [iFocus2AppDelegate release];

    }
    if  (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        //scores
        iFocus2AppDelegate *mainDelegate = (iFocus2AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [mainDelegate flipToHiScores];
        [iFocus2AppDelegate release];
    }
    if  (buttonIndex == 2)
    {
        //setings
        iFocus2AppDelegate *mainDelegate = (iFocus2AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [mainDelegate flipToGameSettings];
        [iFocus2AppDelegate release];
    }
}
```

I pasted these two pieces as I think there must be something wrong specially with GameScreenViewController, as it crashes when it enters this screen for the second time (any other screen flipping (i.e., from alert to HiScores) works. Feel free to ask for any other piece of code you may need, any help will be appreciated.

(Edited): as requested, here's what the console says...

(Edited again): previous pasted code wasn't the real part; even though I have read through all answers, the only code I get back in the console when it crashes is "GDB: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" when in Build&Debug.

Comment: What does the crash report say? If the app crashes then there must be a stack trace etc.

Comment: @Mario, I don't think this is the problem with your code, but check out https://gist.github.com/1525182 where I've edited your code. Make sure to read the commented lines I added.

Comment: In addition to what @JackLawrence said, passing around NSInteger pointers like that is quite odd, and probably a mistake. It doesn't appear to be the cause of the current problem you're seeing, but it will very likely cause trouble later on.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere, something is trying to create a GameScreenViewController, but the `bundle:` part of the selector `initWithNibName:mode:level:bundle:` is being omitted. Based on the backtrace, it would appear to be in your iFocus2AppDelegate's `flipToGameScreen:aLevel:` method, though I don't see it there. You might try cleaning your project in case an old version of the class is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to David Rönnqvist & Chuck mainly, I started to pay further attention to the console, and to that "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" message.

The problem was not a bad call but a bad cleaning of a NSMutableArray, thus creating a memory leak that increased exponentially since I've got a few large loops in some part of my code. I thought that the "release" instruction would clean up anything I created, but it seems not (I must say, I have more programming experience for Android and Windows Phone, I'm trying to translate my solutions into iPhone).

Thus, by adding [myArray RemoveAllObjects] at the beginning of my code, I have solved the problem.

As Ghandi said, you've provided me with a fishing rod rather than a fish. Thanks a lot to the formerly mentioned, as well as to Jack Lawrence for his effort.